# Use excess RAM as cache for Samba?

Tags: server, samba, ram, cache, nas

I have a older workstation with 32gb of RAM that I've repurposed as a server running Ubuntu Server 18.04. Since 32gb is way more than necessary given the limited use (mainly just file sharing and backups), I'm wondering if it's possible to use the remaining RAM as some sort of cache for Samba file sharing (similar to bcache but using RAM instead of SSD). Ramdisk isn't quite what I'm after since I would like the contents in the cache to change based on what is being accessed more frequently.

Is this possible? And if so, could anyone point me towards some resources on how to do it? (Googling thus far has brought me nothing unfortunately)

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You could try and tweak the parameter `write cache size` in `/etc/samba/smb.conf` under the `[global]` entry.

A starting point could be:

```
# for a 256k cache size per file
write cache size = 262144
```

See here for the [property description](https://www.samba.org/samba/samba/docs/man/manpages/smb.conf.5.html#WRITECACHESIZE).

However, it's unlikely that this will result in huge leaps in transfer speed.

Answer (score 1):

I likely wouldn't see much point to the endeavor unless you're teaming up NICs. It's likely that that will be your bottleneck. (1G = 100Mb/s) If it's already on NVME or SSD drives the drives are already faster than the network. A ram disk would be around 20GB/second, and to use that you'd need 10G+ NICs to really get any value.

Since you've mentioned it's an older workstation you probably have only a single 1Gbps interface, so don't sweat it. Currently, that's saturated by anything north of a standard hard drive.

I don't mind doing such things as an experiment, but realize you're doing it just for that and play with it in a VM and not your server that you need to get things done. **:D**

Never invest time in anything that goes faster than your network, a rule to live by.

Comment: “1G = 100Mb/s” this is ambiguous, but assuming you mean “1 Gb/s” then…it’s just wrong. 1 Gb/s = 1000 Mb/s = 125 MB/s.

Answer (score 0):

The requirements for Ubuntu 18.04 minimum advisable for the Desktop version is 2GB. I ran a Samba on an Ubuntu 18.04 with that memory (server version) and I have 12-15 users working continuously. You can quietly use only 2-4 GB. 8 GB, it's already a lot to my understanding

Comment: Yes, but the question was how to benefit from the other 30 GB of free RAM the OP has in his machine.

Comment: No.
See "write cache size (S)" in https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html#WRITECACHESIZE

Comment: Is there a similar parameter for caching reads instead of writes?

Comment: The notes I have are extensive to share here.

I have taken it by analyzing the Samba code from the source code.

I have never had to compile the code.

As it comes in Ubuntu 18.04, with 4GB of RAM, it is enough for me to have 20 users, 10 hours a day, writing and reading documents, videos, backup, and even applications.

Everything depends on what you want it for. In addition to the server, the network connection and the type of OS are determining factors.

Those 20 users are in a 10G network and they are Windows 10.

Comment: To see fine paragraphs of some parameters you can read the following article: https://www.arm-blog.com/samba-finetuning-for-better-transfer-speeds/